# How to write multiple values in a row in one command line with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['column_a'][index] = 1
df['column_b'][index] = 2
df['column_c'][index] = 3
```

How to write 1,2 and 3 in one line? Would that consume 3x less time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `loc` to do this in one assignment:

```
df.loc[index, ['column_a', ...]] = [1, 2, 3]
```

---

If `index` refers to a position and not a label, use

```
df.loc[df.index[index], ['column_a', ...]] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
df['column_a'][index], df['column_b'][index], df['column_c'][index] = 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: This is chained indexing, although not terribly wrong since the result is a scalar, but still, I would recommend one indexing step instead of  multiple.

Comment: @cs95 Your answer is pretty good, didn't think of it, +1 for yours